# Verification: Probability the first card is a king and the second card is a heart

Tags: combinatorics

Two cards are dealt at random from a standard deck of 52 cards. What is the probability that the first card is a King and the second card is a $\heartsuit$?

I think this is the solution:
We have two cases because if the first card is a King, it could be a $\heartsuit$ or not be a $\heartsuit$.

There is a $\dfrac{1}{52}$ chance that the King of $\heartsuit$ is drawn first, and a $\dfrac{12}{51} = \dfrac{4}{17}$ chance that the second card drawn is one of the twelve remaining $\heartsuit$, which gives a probability of $\dfrac{1}{52} \times \dfrac{4}{17} = \dfrac{1}{221}$ chance that this occurs.

There is a $\dfrac{3}{52}$ chance that a non-$\heartsuit$ King is drawn first, and a $\dfrac{13}{51}$ chance that a $\heartsuit$ is drawn second, giving a $\dfrac{3}{52} \times \dfrac{13}{51} = \dfrac{1}{68}$ chance that this occurs.

So the probability that one of these two cases happens is $\dfrac{1}{221} + \dfrac{1}{68} = \boxed{\dfrac{1}{52}}$.

I'm not sure so can someone check over?

Comment: Looks fine. ${}{}{}$

Comment: See also this question and answers: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4407424/why-probability-of-a-diamond-followed-by-an-ace-on-drawing-2-cards-from-a-shuf/4407442#4407442

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is correct.

Another way to see this is that, given any rank $r$ and suit $s,$ the probability $p$ that the first card is of rank $r$ and the second card is of suit $s$ is independent of $r,s.$

Also, any draw of two cards is associated with only one rank of the first card and one suit of the second card.

Since there are $52$ pairs $(r,s),$ this means $52p=1$ or $p=\frac1{52}.$

Note, this reasoning works with or without replacement. So you could pick a random card, put it back, shuffle, and pick another random card. The probability will still be $\frac1{52}.$

This also works for every deck $D$ of size $\geq RS$ with an injection $$\{1,\dots,R\}\times\{1,\dots,S\}\to D.$$ The cards in $D$ which are not in the image are like jokers, with no rank or suit. So we will write $J=|D|-RS.$

Then the probability that the first card has rank $r$ and suit $s,$ without replacement, is: $$\frac{1}{RS}\cdot \frac{RS(RS-1)}{|D|(|D|-1)}=\frac{RS-1}{|D|(|D|-1)}=\frac{1}{|D|}-\frac{J}{|D|(|D|-1)}$$

With replacement, you get $$\frac{1}{RS}\frac{(RS)^2}{|D|^2}=\frac{1}{|D|}-\frac{J}{|D|^2}$$